# NumberFormatter error

Tags: symfony

I have WampServer 2.5 (Apache 2.4.9 and PHP 5.5.12),and I enable php_intl (it marked) also I've had to copy

C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\icu**51.dll

to

C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin

Then I restart the wamp

when i load my form, i receive an error:

> Warning: NumberFormatter::formatCurrency(): Number formatting failed in C:\wamp\www\elitetest_m\vendor\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\MoneyType.php line 97

how to do to solve this problem ?

Thank you in advance.(Excuse my English)

Comment: Have you checked with a phpinfo that intl is really enabled?

Comment: yes i checked with phpinfo() ,intl is really enabled